# R Shiny Report Generator

Tags: r, download, shiny, report, r-markdown

I am trying to develop an app that allows the user to download a report.
Here there is a really simple code to try this out.

```
shinyApp(
ui = fluidPage(
sliderInput("slider", "Slider", 1, 100, 50),
downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
),
server = function(input, output) {
output$report <- downloadHandler(
  filename = "report.html",
  content = function(file) {
    tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
    file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
    params <- list(n = input$slider)
rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
      params = params,
      envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
    )
  }
)
}
)
```

The problem is that the download does not work, I get a weird error, here there is the picture:

[image: error]

Can anyone help please?
Thanks

Comment: Because your `report.Rmd` doesn't exist or if yes, it's in a different path

Comment: Agree with @amrrs.. Try printing your path somewhere and check if it's the right one.